# I Finished My Film. How to Get It to Theatres?

Tags: theater

We finally finished our amazing professional full-length film.

Whew! Long work.

The thing is everything was done by our team, as in no contracts with major companies, distributors, etc.

Are there any ways we can distribute our film to cinemas or stores? What are some steps to follow? Does a representative go to each theatre and present the film, or...?

Thank you.

Comment: What about monetized distribution on the internet?  I don't know how all of the rules work for sites like vimeo, but maybe you could find a distribution channel that would get A) money B) exposure and C) let you retain copyright.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems odd that you'd put in the time, money and effort needed for a 'professional' film with no idea what to do when you're done. In any case, one route would be through the festival circuit, where several successful films have found distributors. Your film needs exposure now, and you won't get it unless you explore every avenue.

And you will need a distributor: no significant theater or group will take on your film without one. An agent can help you get to distributors. It isn't unusual for a professionally produced film to spend almost as much on promotion and distribution as on initial production. If you can't afford it, you have to make a deal with someone who can.

At the very least you'll need to create a DCP (digital cinema package) and DVD screener copies for any festivals or agents you contact. Check the web sites of the major and minor festivals to see their submission requirements. Good luck.